# Bitbucket Pipeline with AWS EB and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on figuring out deploying a Wordpress site from BB Pipelines to AWS EB. It all makes sense except for one thing, I want the repository to only contain the theme and plugin files.

I do not want the full WP directory being deployed each time. Media would be handled via an S3 bucket and the DB would use RDS.

What is the best way to get WP installed but only have the theme and plugins deploy through Pipelines? And when I want to update to the latest version of WP, how would that work?

Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: We have solved this problem partly. By putting the wp-content folder into BB. Rest of the part will be the same. Also you can call a script to run wp-cli commands to install WordPress for you after deployment.

Comment: You can get help on wp-cli from a series of instruction here : https://www.wordpress-studio.io/wordpress-and-wp-cli-part-1/

Comment: Based on the answer below, why do you choose to use this method versus uploading the whole wordpress core? I don't upload the whole core, for church and state reasons. I don't want others working on our site modifying the core elements.

My issue with installing via wp-cli is I have custom wp-config that uses the AWS variables for dbname, pw, etc. Also it has the .ebextensions folder included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution, and best practice in my humble opinion, is to repo the entire WordPress installation, including the WordPress core, and all your custom themes and plugins.

Having the entire installation in one repo solves many problems: you can can tag and release versions, and you can install all software locally with a simple git clone.

Regarding the file system, definitely consider EFS instead of S3. It is much more reliable and easier to mount in a linux-based system. Make sure and define set the file path environment variable, so you can point WordPress to the files. You will want mount this outside of the software file tree.

I have been running this kind of setup for 3 years with no problems. We do releases through the code deploy service daily. Very straightforward and easy to maintain.

To upgrade WordPress just check out the current version from the repo, then apply the upgrades release, do comparisons, test commit and release.

Comment: Would you recommend EFS over S3 with Cloudfront?

Comment: I use EFS for file storage, then expose the site itself as the orgin for cloudfront. As I mentioned, EFS is better for filesystem storage and can be directly mounted to your instance.